# I think I overstayed by 1 day on F1 visa, will it impact re-entry on a different visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I think I have accrued 1 day overstay on F1 visa beyond 60 day grace period. Different online tools give different results. My 60 grace period began from Oct 24th 2017 and I left on Dec 23rd 2017, I thought it is 60 days :S. Assuming it is 61 days, will it impact my re-entry getting into US again?

I read that students on F1 and J1 don't accrue unlawful presence till its pointed out by a judge or USCIS ( its revised in May 2018). I am currently not present in the US for 5 months. Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Whether you accrued unlawful presence is relevant only to whether you triggered an automatic ban, which you didn't in any event because you need180 days of unlawful presence to trigger the ban.  Why do you think your grace period began on October 24?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got my H1b rejection notice on Oct 24th, I calculated  60 days using an online tool and booked my tickets for Dec 23rd. When I came back to India my brother pointed out that I may have overstayed by a day.

Comment: I believe the grace period starts on the document date, not the date of receipt.  But if the document was dated Oct 24th, I think your assumption is faulty.  By inductive reasoning, if there had been no grace period, you would have had to leave on Oct 24th.  If the grace period had been 1 day, you would have had to leave by Oct 25th.  If 2 days, Oct 26th.  Keep going, and you reach the statement "if 60 days, December 23."

Comment: Yes, this makes sense!  So, should I answer no to the question where it is asked if I ever overstayed? Does USCIS uses same way of calculation?

Comment: I'm not sure how USCIS calculates it, but if you ask at [Expatriates.SE] you may find someone who knows.

Comment: I'm doubtful about the assumption that an H-1B denial date in October would mark the start of the F-1 grace period.  If you still had unexpired OPT at the time, the OPT would still be valid. If you were only on Cap Gap, your grace period [may have started October 1](https://www.nafsa.org/Professional_Resources/Browse_by_Interest/International_Students_and_Scholars/The_60-Day_F-1_Grace_Period_and_Adjudication_or_Revocation_of_Cap-Gap_Petitions_After_October_1/).